# Use @include directive for more than one field

Tags: graphql, relayjs

I have a relay container that conditionally fetches some fields using `@include(if: $variable)`, but I have to write the directive for each individual field:

```
const relayOptions = {
  initialVariables: {
    expandDetails: false,
  },
  fragments: {
    company: Relay.QL`
      fragment on Company {
        id
        name
        employees @include(if: $expandDetails) {
          fullName
        }
        admins @include(if: $expandDetails) {
          fullName
        }
        departments @include(if: $expandDetails) {
          name
        }
      }
    `,
  },
}
```

Is there any way that I could write the directive only once, for example something like this (and I know this code won't work):

```
const relayOptions = {
  initialVariables: {
    expandDetails: false,
  },
  fragments: {
    company: Relay.QL`
      fragment on Company {
        id
        name
        @include(if: $expandDetails) {
          employees {
            fullName
          }
          admins {
            fullName
          }
          departments {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  },
}
```

I tried some other crazy ways but none of them worked, I got this error:

> '@include' can't be applied to fragment definitions (allowed: fields, fragment spreads, inline fragments)

Edit: Note: I need to do that to avoid fetching data unnecessarily. I'd like to only fetch the data if the collapsible component displaying the data is expanded (planning to do that using `setVariables` after component is mounted).
In this example there are only 3 conditional fields, but in the actual case I'm trying to solve for there is a lot more than that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put the directive on an inline fragment, and just use the same type as the outer field:

```
fragment on Company {
  ... on Company @include(if: $expandDetails) {
    employees { fullName }
    admins { fullName }
    departments { fullName }
  }
}
```